# How to create table like this with check box?

Tags: html, css, tabular

How to create table like this with check box?

I tried but could not do so.

I also want the content to wrap not extend beyond the specified width.

[image]

Comment: Like what? Do you have an image (I can't see one, but that might be because it could be blocked)?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs He did supply an image. So it's probably blocked on your end

Comment: If you like my answer please check it as answered. Andy's answer is similar but you should always use "" quotes for attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Allthough don't use inline styles (style="") as my example, put css in a seperate .css file.

```
<table style="max-width: 500px;">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td colspan="7">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't need three rows. Actually, the colspan=6 here will do quite the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5a8k/

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=2><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td colspan=7>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td> 
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td> 
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td> 
</tr>​
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HBb7F/)**):

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=2 class='tdCheckbox'><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td colspan=7>a</td>
</tr>
<tr class='trMain'>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td> 
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td> 
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td> 
</tr>
</table>​
```